# createWriteStream finishes, but file not available

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, watson

My node server uses Watson TTS api to synthesize text sent by the client using POST. Writes TTs stream to a file named using a counter (1.ogg,2.ogg...), and once finished, sends back filename. Client loads it into audio tag and plays audio.

Although I am using createWriteStream's on('finish'), I sometimes get an error client-side where the file can't be loaded, as if not there yet:

```
GET http://localhost/tts_server/audio/24.ogg 412 (Precondition Failed)
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

Additionally,it ALWAYS fails if counter (and so filename) is 1. And it OFTEN fails if the text to synthesize is long.

Client-side relevant code

```
$.post("http://192.168.0.4:3000", { text : text }, function(data){
  player.src = 'audio/' + data.count + '.ogg';
  player.oncanplaythrough = player.play();
});
```

Server-side relevant code

```
var count = 10;

// function to TTS with Watson
function syntText(texto, cb){
    var tts = new TextToSpeechV1 ({
      username: '****',
      password: '****'
    });
    var params = {
      text: texto,
      voice: 'es-ES_EnriqueVoice',
      accept: 'audio/ogg;codecs=opus'
    };
    var ws = fs.createWriteStream('../audio/' + count + '.ogg');
    ws.on('finish', cb);
    tts.synthesize(params).pipe(ws);
}

// post 
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    syntText(req.body.text, function(){ //body parser here
        res.json({count : count});
        count++;
    }); 
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Could it be the static file server not detecting the new file or caching it?

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat . I am not sure what do you mean. Could you please elaborate? Thank you

Comment: I'm thinking whatever is serving the file, could not be detecting the newly written file and thus creating problems. But now that I think about it, it could be the browser cache having problems. Try it after resetting the cache.

Comment: Or instead, try random number as the file number.

Comment: Hmm... I'd make sure if the ```tts.synthesize(params)``` doesn't return an already ended stream... that's the only case I can think of when the finished callback could get called before the file was created...